How does null === null is true in javascript when typeOf null is an object?
Can someone help me understand how could the following statements true in javascript:

 null == null     true
 null === null    true

when typeof null is object and since objects are reference type and no two object can have same address space and can't be equal in both the cases then how it could be true

that's because null is a primitive value, not an object

Here is the specification: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/overview.html#sec-null-value "4.4.15 null value primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value"

Here is the reason why typeof null === "object": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#typeof_null It's rather a bug.

null isn't really an object. It's a historical accident that typeof null == 'object'

See Why is typeof null "object"?

"no two object can have same address space and can't be equal in both the cases then how it could be true" - even if null was an actual object, why do you assume that null === null does not compare that singleton null object with itself?
